# Two differents `EXPLAIN` with two identical servers and two identical databases

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

- I have two physical servers :

  - prod : CPU 2.3GHz 4proc
  - dev : CPU 2.6GHz 2proc
  - prod & dev : 8GB RAM
- The two have `PostgreSQL14` and `PostGIS 3.2`. The `postgresql.conf` files are identical :

  - work_mem 100MB,
  - shared_buffers 2GB,
  - max_connection 70,
  - effective_cache_size 6GB.
- A query is executed on the **same** database on each server : the database dev is a **copy** of prod. This query is automatic, I can't modify it.
- The issue :
  After an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, BUFFERS) very_long_query` , the execution times are very different :

  - prod: >= 6min
  - dev: ~ 45sec

I am not familiar with execution plan (and haven't been a dba forever) but I can say that seqscan on one table is involved in the difference. For example :

- #21:

  - seqscan: prod 38sec, dev 8sec
  - shared hit/read : prod 1/299596, dev 8074/117548
- There are at least **7** nodes with these differences : #21, #120, #223, #245, #306, #339, #363 (prod server).

How can buffers shared and hit be so different? Since PostgreSQL is the same, is it "just" a matter of physical config?

[Link to prod plan](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/ch626d868ch3b427)
[Link to dev plan](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/abh4cce99g63f08a)

Comment: Have you run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on both?

Comment: You're selecting 32 times from the same table uniteobservation. Looks like this could be done in just a single select

Comment: I can't modify the query. It is a automatic query from`QGIS`. And to answer to a question you are going to ask, I did contact `QGIS` dev about all this, waiting now. I let PostgresQL handle `autovacuum` in general, so maybe I have to do it by myself asap ?

Comment: Unfortunately, `vacuum` has changed nothing (there are  lots of more insert than delete on the table).

Comment: How did you make dev be a copy of prod?  Presumably prod is bloated and you did it in a way such that dev is not bloated.  That doesn't seem to be the full story though, probably dev has faster storage as well as being less bloated.  You didn't describe the storage hardware for either one of them.

Comment: I did not make a copy, my colleagues from IT department did. I did make the copy of the database. I will ask about the hardware. (with google traduction I would say that bloated is for dev not for prod ?)

Comment: It is not the `VACUUM` that is important it is the `ANALYZE`. Run just `ANALYZE` on the table.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part: I ran `ANALYZE` few days ago. Stats are up to date. Moreover, I have increased `default_statistics_target = 200`